# "Cannot find -lqjpeg" error when compiling static QT application

Tags: qt, plugins, qt4, static-libraries

I am trying to compile a (Windows) QT application in static (release configuration) mode using Nokia's QT Creator. I compiled QT itself statically as per standard instructions [here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/How_to_build_a_static_Qt_version_for_Windows_with_gcc). However, despite running configure.exe with -qt-libjpeg I am still getting the following error:

> mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lqjpeg
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

.pro file does contain QTPLUGIN += qjpeg

.cpp file does contain Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(qjpeg)

The project I am trying to compile is called CutyCapt and can be downloaded [here](http://cutycapt.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/cutycapt/CutyCapt.tar.gz?view=tar). I am using QT v.4.7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be issues if you've not got the Qt libraries in your path, if you check your environment variables you should have a reference to the Qt libraries path, if not then you'll need to add it yourself.

Comment: I narrowed down the error to not having qjpeg.a in my plugins/imageformats folder. Despite passing -qt-libjpeg to configure.exe, I still can't force mingw32 to recompile the plugins for static use. Any suggestions?

Comment: Been a while since I've touched a Windows box so not sure how much I can help from here out. I'll have a look at my notes and see if I have anything from way back then.